# Check if URL is an image?

Tags: php

This has been asked before, but most, if not all answers, were either solutions that didn't work in all situations or were unnecessary (like using `getimagesize()`, which downloads the entire image).

How would I check if a given URL leads to an image *without having to hardcode image extensions* (like `.png`', `.jpg`, etc.)?

Comment: Check content-type of the server's response. But for more details file should be downloaded and analyzed.

Comment: You can't do this reliably without downloading the entire image, because you have to actually read the file type (and thus need the file) to do it reliably in all situations. (Unless as @Cheery points out you're willing to trust the server to tell you.)

Answer (score 1):

You can read only file header by CURL and then detect if the header is image header or not.

```
curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $file_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$header = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if (strstr($header, 'image/png')) {
//file is image
}
```